# Can TeamCity check out code to more than one machine

Tags: tfs, teamcity

Can I have TeamCity Build server check out code to another server or machine, in addition to itself? What I am asking is can I run build configurations that automatically checks out, udpates source code from TFS into multiple servers. Each Build configuration handling a different server?

Answer (score 2):

I didnt try it myself, but waht you could try is to set the "Checkout directory" in the "Version Control settings" to an network dir. for example

> \10.30.9.1\d$\project\

or "map" a network drive on the TeamCity Build server